# Problemas com checkbox num adapter view de android

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem de exemplo mostra três checkbox numa linha de uma listview. Mas tenho que fazer uma forma na qual, ao marcar 1 checkbox desmarque os outros da mesma linha que estiverem marcados. Tem como fazer isso?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        PedidoItem item = itens.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_separacao, null);

        TextView referencia = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_ref_sep);
        referencia.setText(item.getProduto());

        TextView tamanho = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tam_sep);
        tamanho.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTamanho()));

        CheckBox separado = view.findViewById(R.id.ch_sep);
        CheckBox corrigir = view.findViewById(R.id.ch_corrigir);
        CheckBox manual = view.findViewById(R.id.ch_manual);

        return view;
    }
```

Tentei fazendo isso:

```
if(corrigir.isChecked()){
    separado.setChecked(false);
    manual.setChecked(false);
}

if(manual.isChecked()){
    separado.setChecked(false);
    corrigir.setChecked(false);
}
```

mesmo assim não desmarca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta algo mais ou menos assim

`seuCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {`

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(corrigir.isChecked()){
                        separado.setChecked(false);
                        manual.setChecked(false);
                    }

                    if(manual.isChecked()){
                        separado.setChecked(false);
                        corrigir.setChecked(false);
                    }
        }
```

`}`